# Truffle Drizzle: Passing String address results in Invalid Number of Parameters

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, drizzle

I have a view function in my contract that takes an address as a parameter and returns a uint:

```
function getNumber(address _address) public view returns (uint) {
    require(_address != 0x0);
    return theList[_address].length;
}
```

In my App.js:

```
this.contracts.TheContract.methods.getNumber(this.state.account).call()
```

where:

```
this.state.account
```

is set in the constructor

Result:

```
Error: Invalid number of parameters for "getNumber". Got 42 expected 1
```

I tried converting to a byte array but that produces other errors.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: how do you initialize this.state.account?

Comment: constructor(props, context) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        account: props.accounts[0]
      }
      console.log("account = " + this.state.account)
    }

Comment: not sure honestly. did you tried to cast at string (using toString())? It seems that is getting each char of the address as single parameter which is strange.

Comment: I am not sure what I between then and now, but it works now.