# Hoiw to convert string to address with web3

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-contract

I am getting address value with html input as string value how do we convert the string to address for parsing with truffle-contract.

Here's the method I am using:

```
registerAirline : async() => {
        const airline = document.getElementById('airlineAddress').value;
        const flightApp = await flightSuretyApp.deployed();
        await flightApp.registerAirline(web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(airline), {from: account});
    },
```

I am getting this error as it's not able to parse string address as address format.

> Error: Invalid number of parameters for "registerAirline". Got 2
>   expected 4!

Well the parameters are correct in case I will paste them down here too.

Here's the function for flightSuretyApp

```
function registerAirline(address airline) external requireIsOperational() airlineIsFunded(msg.sender) airlineIsNotRegistered(airline) returns (bool success, uint256 votes) {
        if (getRegisteredAirlines() < MULTIPARTY_MINMUM_AIRLINES) {
            flightSuretyData.registerAirline(airline, msg.sender);
            airlineMultiCallers[airline] = [msg.sender];
            return (success, airlineMultiCallers[airline].length);
        } else {
            bool isDuplicate = false;
            for (uint c = 0; c < airlineMultiCallers[airline].length; c ++) {
                if (airlineMultiCallers[airline][c] == msg.sender) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            require(!isDuplicate, "Voting airline has already submitted vote for this new airline");

            airlineMultiCallers[airline].push(msg.sender);
            if (airlineMultiCallers[airline].length >= getRegisteredAirlines().div(MULTIPARTY_CONSENSUS_DIVIDER)) {
                flightSuretyData.registerAirline(airline, msg.sender);
                return (success, airlineMultiCallers[airline].length);
            }

            return (false, airlineMultiCallers[airline].length);
        }
    }
```

Here's the code for flightSuretyData:

```
function registerAirline(address airline, address caller) external requireIsOperational isAuthorizedCaller isAirlineFunded(caller) {
            airlines[airline] = Airline(true, false);
            registeredAirlines = registeredAirlines + 1;
            emit AirlineRegistered(airline);
    }
```

Comment: There's no function here which takes 4 parameters, meaning - the code that you've posted and the error that you've posted are not related.

Comment: Also, any reason for that last piece of code in your question? Is it there in order to add some confusion to the reader?

Comment: @goodvibration that's why the problem seems with the string address from the html. Well they are the functions for registerAirline()

Comment: `expected 4` implies that the **solidity** function takes 4 parameters. No such function in your code.

Comment: @goodvibration buts that function I am calling in my index.js I did re-checked with the typos incase but those are the functions from two contracts. The required parameter is 1 for the 1st contract which inherits the function from another contract with 2 parameters.

Comment: There's no inheritance when function prototypes are not identical, so I'm not really sure what you mean by that last statement of yours, which leads me to suspect that there are some other issues in your codes, and perhaps a relevant part of it which you haven't even posted.

Comment: @goodvibration do you know how we can convert string address from html input value to address format or account format for truffle-contract.js

Comment: @SagarAtalatti Do you have some reason to believe the error is related to the format of the address? E.g. does it work when you manually specify an address? Otherwise, I would assume the error means exactly what it says: that the function is supposed to receive 4 parameters but is only receiving 2. You're definitely passing two parameters (one that the Solidity function expects and one with the extra transaction parameters), so the question is why the function expects two more. Could be a mismatch between the ABI and the current contract code. Try to recompile everything?

Comment: @goodvibration I think what he's saying is that `flightSuretyApp` inherits from `flightSuretyData` and thus has both functions: `registerAirline(address)` and `registerAirline(address,address)`.

Comment: Note that we're looking for a Solidity function that takes **three** parameters. That would lead to a JavaScript function expecting **four** parameters (because of the extra transaction parameters, e.g. `{ from: ... }`) and cause the error message we're seeing.

Comment: @smarx: I'm aware of all that, but there's no Solidity function here which takes more than 2 parameters, so I don't really see an "entry point" here. The error and the code don't seem to align with each other.

Comment: @goodvibration I understand the parameters is one for the function in FlightSuretyApp and provides msg.sender in the second one which has two parameters. The error definitely doesn't make any sense for four parameters but that's the only function which I am calling.

Comment: @goodvibration there's same issue reported it here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/43798/42543

Comment: Yes, but in this case the error says `expected 1`, and the Solidity function indeed takes 1 argument!